# How many elements are there in a total ordering T of a set A with |A| = n?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many elements are there in a total ordering T of a set A with |A| = n?

I have no clue on how to do this problem. If someone could let me know how to start the problem, it would be much appreciated.thanks

Comment: Could you clarify the question? The set will obviously have $n$ elements. If you're asking the number of possible total orderings, consider how many possibilities you have for assigning the least element, then the second least, and so on.

Comment: @Neil: If I had to guess, I'd guess the question is about the order itself, namely the set of ordered pairs.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $T$ is a subset of $A\times A$, so it can have at most $n^2$ elements. $T$ is reflexive, transitive, and antisymmetric, and for each pair of distinct elements $x$ and $y$ of $A$, exactly one $\langle x,y\rangle$ and $\langle y,x\rangle$ belongs to $T$. That’s enough information to determine how many of the ordered pairs in $A\times A$ belong to $T$.

To get a clearer picture, you might want to look at the case in which $A=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, and $T$ is the usual order on $A$; all linear orders on $A$ are exactly like this one, but with the elements of $A$ permuted, so they all have the same number of ordered pairs.

Comment: Note that you'll get different answers depending on whether, when you talk about a "total order," you mean "$\le$" or "$<$".

Comment: @Noah: I thought about saying something but then decided to wait to see whether the OP objected to reflexivity. (I also dislike the use of linear/total order for $<$: that’s a *strict* linear order, dammit! `:-)`)